# Pointers: why the output is 6?

Tags: c, string, pointers

The output of the program below is `6`. I am not able to figure out why. When I trace it out by hand, I am getting `5`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
    int i,count=0; 
    char *p1="abcdefghij"; 
    char *p2="alcmenfoip"; 

    for(i=0;i<=strlen(p1);i++) { 
        if(*p1++ == *p2++) 
            count+=5; 
        else 
            count-=3; 
    } 
    printf("count=%d",count); 
}
```

Comment: shouldnt the output be anyway 2? or 7? demands on what you were expecting? I don't get how you even expect 6?!

Comment: @Zaibis ` ./a.out
count=6`

Comment: move strlen(p1) before for. on every iteration strlen returns number lesser by one - because it returns number of characters from char at which p1 is pointing to \0. your for will execute only 5 times.

Comment: @Zaibris: It actually only checks the first 6 chars, since `p1` is moved ahead in the loop body.

Answer (score 9):

`if(*p1++ == *p2++)` is reading both `p1` and `p2` character by character. When the characters are the same, it will increase `count` by 5, else it will decrement it by 3. But, there is another thing that you didn't pay attention to: `strlen(p1)` will always be different in each iteration, because `p1` will change. So, in each iteration, you also need to check its value.

```
p1   p2 count   i   strlen (before entering into the loop body)
a    a   5      0   10
b    l   2      1   9
c    c   7      2   8
d    m   4      3   7
e    e   9      4   6
f    n   6      5   5  <- No more - this is the last one
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is, `strlen(p1)` changes every iteration. So loop condition goes

```
0 <= 10  +5
1 <= 9   -3
2 <= 8   +5 
3 <= 7   -3
4 <= 6   +5
5 <= 5   -3
```

So equal characters are `a`, `c`, `e`, shown as +5 above. Total is 6.

Answer (score 0):

Your program stops when `i>strlen(p1)` because you are changing p1 each time you do `*p1++`.

When it computes the condition strlen returns the size from the las char.

If you store the value in a variable at the beginning (before your loop) it should work.

Anyway, try to avoid pointer arithmetic...